# how to upgrade from ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10?

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

i was upgrading to 15.10 with these two commands that i found on ubuntu forums:

```
sudo sed -i 's/vivid/wily/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but at some point it showed network failure and it stopped so i tried this command:

```
apt-get update
```

but the problem i encountered is that even on rebooting on screen it flashes 15.04
now if i redo the upper two commands will it create duplicate repositories that i will have to take care of? because i dont have enough space on my laptop to waste. and any other detail for my upgrade to 15.10 would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Not only you do the wrong thing by replacing the release name in the repository list to upgrade but also Willy is the current development Ubuntu release and as such it is not (yet) supported in Askubuntu.

Comment: Clearly you did `sudo some_command_I_do_not_understand`. This is **ALWAYS** unwise. The `sed` command changes all occurrances of the string `"vivid"` to the string `"willy"` in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.   If it worked the first time, it will have nothing to do the second time.

Comment: Do sudo `sed -i 's/wily/vivid/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` and then run update. Then start over

Comment: @waltinator you are pretty close but at that time i rechecked that post was made by some person with high reputation at forum. i am just a beginner and i will keep your advice in mind.

Comment: i dont know why the question has been marked duplicate as it was very specific problem that i faced . nevertheless thnx for the support!

Comment: It's called "wily" not "willy" :-) since this is a really old question, soon Ubuntu 15.10 will only be available in the archived packages: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Please be aware that 15.10 is still in development. Development releases are unstable, and not suited for people who do not want to fix/report/triage bugs. If you want a stable Ubuntu version, stick to the official released versions. For added stability, choose a Ubuntu LTS release.

That said, to upgrade to a development release open your terminal by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `update-manager -d`.

[image]

You can choose to upgrade from this window.

Or, If you prefer to do this from the command-line,

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```